# How to lookup in another collection with objectID of main collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the data from another collection via lookup

collection "users"

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f"
    },
    "name":"Dave",
    "center":"THGJ556",


}
```

collection "addresses"

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f"
    },
    "userId":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f",    
}
```

collection "applications"

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f"
    },
    "userId":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f",
    "centerId":"THGJ556",   

},
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d3647j"
    },
    "userId":"60bf4bb31f45d98903d1851f",
    "centerId":"JHGJ5476",  

}
```

Now I need data from all the tables.

here is my code:

```
users.aggregate([
        
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "addresses",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "userId",
            as: "addressData"
          }
        },

        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "applications",
            pipeline: [
              { $match: 
                { userId:"$_id", centerId: "JHGJ5476"} 
              },
           ],
           as: "applicationData"
          }
        },
        
      ] ,function(err,  result) {
        
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          
        } else {
          console.log(result)
        }        
      });
```

I am doing something wrong while using aggregate and match in pipeline.

I am getting addressData correctly, but I get nothing [] in applicationData because I suspect something is wrong with userId:"$_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-pipeline) explain:

> A $match stage requires the use of an $expr operator to access the variables. $expr allows the use of aggregation expressions inside of the $match syntax.

So you have to use `$expr` into `$match` stage and also a `let` stage.

- `let` stage is to define variable to use into `$expr`: `id: $_id`.
- `$expr` used with `$and` and `$eq` is to get both conditions.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "addresses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "addressData"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "applications",
      let: {"id": "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {"$eq": ["$userId","$$id"]},
                {"$eq": ["$centerId","JHGJ5476"]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "applicationData"
    }
  }
])
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4WNkW4Wfjhv) example.

Comment: thanks, I tried above solution but it only works by making userId convert to objectId, any specific reason for that?  {"$eq": [ { "$toObjectId": "$userId" }, "$$id"]},

Comment: Maybe query is getting `_id` as string and comparing to `ObjectId` return false. Using mongoose I used to use a method who returns a new ObjectId: `function generateObjectId(id) { return Types.ObjectId(id) }`. Then you can use this method into the query instead of use `$toObjectId`. But is the same, is to compare ObjectId vs ObjectId instead of String vs ObjectId.